# Reviewing the implementation of a function that splits character types

Tags: c++, string, templates, split, rvalue-reference

I needed to have a helper for splitting a string by a delimiter. So I've wrote this code:

```
import std;

template <typename T>
concept SplittableString =
    std::is_same_v<const char*, std::remove_reference_t<T>> ||
    std::is_same_v<std::string, std::remove_reference_t<T>> ||
    std::is_same_v<std::string_view, std::remove_reference_t<T>>;


template <SplittableString T>
auto split_str(T&& str, const char* delimiter) -> std::vector<std::string> {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;

    std::istringstream iss;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>, std::string_view)
        iss = std::istringstream(std::string {str});
    else
        iss = std::istringstream(std::forward<T>(str));

    std::string token;
    while (std::getline(iss, token, *delimiter))
        tokens.push_back(token);

    return tokens;
}


int main() {
    const char* s1 = "I am a pointer to a (const) char";
    auto splitted_s1 = split_str(s1, " ");
    std::cout << "s1: ";
    for (auto& spl : splitted_s1)
        std::cout << spl << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::string s2 = "I am an std::string!";
    auto splitted_s2 = split_str(s2, " ");
    std::cout << "s2: ";
    for (auto& spl : splitted_s2)
        std::cout << spl << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    std::string_view s3 {"I am an std::string_view!"};
    auto splitted_s3 = split_str(s3, " ");
    std::cout << "s3: ";
    for (auto& spl : splitted_s3)
        std::cout << spl << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

But I am not sure about a lot of things. Neither I am aware about the potential pitfalls of this code?

The unique constraints are that the callee can be a `const char*`, an `std::string` or an `std::string_view`. So, those three types are splittable character types.

Can someone make a review of this code and tell me all the points where I am not doing the things correctly?

Specially, I am not sure about the `iss` asignment part in the `if constexpr` block.

Here's a live working example: https://godbolt.org/z/j8dnvs8d7

EDIT: Bonus. Why are all the types deduced as lvalue-references when they bind to the `str` parameter? Because all parameters on a function are themselves lvalues?

Comment: Probably belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Before posting on Code Review please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Concepts add an unnecassary complexity here. I recommend using overloaded functions here.

Comment: Furthermore it may be desirable to go with the cheaper option of returning `std::string_view`s referring to parts of the existing string instead of creating copies; the drawback of course would be possibility of that string no longer being valid. E.g. the following could be used instead of the concept and would even work for C++17: `std::vector<std::string> split_str(std::string&&, char const*); std::vector<std::string_view> split_str(std::string_view, char const*); auto split_str(char const* x, char const* y) {return spilt_std(std::string_view(x), y); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good implementation, but maybe too complex.

You may take advantage of 4 properties:

1. `std::string` has many [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). It can especially be constructed from other `std::string`s, `std::string_view`s and also from `const char *`
2. a `std::vector` has also a range [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). Number 5 in the list. So, it can be constructed by a "begin" / "end" iterator pair.
3. There is a dedicated iterator for iterating over patterns in a `std::string`, or in a negative way, use a delimiter.
4. We can write generic lambdas

If we combine all the above, we can come up with a simple lambda, that will do the job for you.

Please see the the following short code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <string_view>

const std::regex delimiter{ "R( )" };

int main() {
    auto split = [&](auto& str) { std::string s(str);  std::vector<std::string> v(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), delimiter, -1), {}); return v; };

    // Test Data
    std::string s{ "aaa bbb ccc" };
    std::string_view sv{ "ddd eee fff" };
    const char* c = "ggg hhh iii";

    // Debug output
    for (const auto& p : split(s)) std::cout << p << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
    for (const auto& p : split(sv)) std::cout << p << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
    for (const auto& p : split(c)) std::cout << p << ' '; std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Let us have a look.

The lambda will be defined generic, so it can be called with all kind of parameters.  In the lambda, we will create a temporary `std::string` from the parameter. This will work for all your 3 needed types, because of the existing constructors. So, now we have a `std::string` containing the provided data.

Next, we will define a `std::vector<std::string>` and and use its constructor no 5. So, we will provide a begin-iterator and an end-iterator.

The iterator that we will use is the [std::sregex_token_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator). This iterator has also some [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator). We can survive with No 1 and No 2.

No 1 ist the default constructor. And as you can read in the CPP-Reference

> Default constructor. Constructs the end-of-sequence iterator.

No. 2 takes the `begin`- and `end`-iterator of our temporary string, a regex, and then -1 as the `submatch`. Again from the CPP-reference:

> submatch  -   the index of the submatch that should be returned. "0" represents the entire match, and "-1" represents the parts that are not matched (e.g, the stuff between matches).

So, now we know, how to use the both iterators. If we construct the `std::vector` we give it:

`std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), delimiter, -1)` as the begin iterator ans `{}` as the default, so the end-iterator.

Now, we have all the data that we need in our vector, just be defining it and using its constructor.

And that's it. We return the `std::vector` with the string parts and can work with them.

Comment: your implementation looks really fine! And definitly more readable and mantainable. Just one thing that I don't grasp. Temporary string? Why temporary? I mean, `s` is just an allocated value, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexVergara for `std::sregex_token_iterator` to work the begin() and end() iterators have to comply to a specific concept. Intuitively string_view as an argument should suffice and cover all the cases (it does not, I did check, at least not as a drop-in replacement), but well... this is C++ so it cannot be that easy ;)

Comment: @Alagner you're completly right. Thanks for pointing that out!